# Extract html from OutputCache Buffer

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I try to intercept textraw from my Custom OutputCacheProvider CacheEntry Buffer.

when I use  `cacheEntry.ResponseElements.First()` I get the Half of my html page, but when I try to concat all chunck, I've get a crapy response (looks like binary serialized data).
How can I do someting like :

```
IOutputCacheEntry cacheEntry = cachedItem.Item as IOutputCacheEntry;
StringBuilder textResponse = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var responseRaw in cacheEntry.ResponseElements.Where(s=>!(s is FileResponseElement )))
                {

                    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])responseRaw.GetType().GetField("_buffer",
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                        BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(responseRaw);
                    textResponse.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));    
                }
```

**edit : I tried to concat all byte[] before "Stringify" them, and I tried with UTF-8 encoding.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right encoding? `Encoding.Default` returns the encoding for the current system ANSI codepage. This might not work if you're using UTF-8 or some other encoding. You should check the `Content-type:` header to identify the correct encoding to use.

Comment: I will try with the content-type header